# Mysql mistake when adding a table so a script

Tags: mysql, database, apache, scripting

Mysql mistake (don't laught please)

I made a script that generates statistics table for my site. This script generates over 2000 tables that are used for different statistics data with a different granularity like:

- tables by years
- tables by day
- tables by users
- tables by user_agent

etc... (don't ask me why this, it was made by the previous so called architect -  altought they load in less than 0.02 seconds)

So I updated the script to add new tables but i made a mistake.

I put a space in the table name and now I cannot delete it. so i try to put a \ to escape it but no success:

```
root@summary:reports> drop table xd_2012_02_\ ua;
ERROR: 
Unknown command '\ '.
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\ ua' at line 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use the **`** - This will treat the string passed as the actual table name and not a bunch of commands you want to execute.

```
root@summary:reports> drop table `xd_2012_02_\ ua`;
```

This should show:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I would recommend to use the **`** not only for this case, but also that will prevent errors if you use reserved MySQL words like `type` or `desc` (as description) for columns or table names. This might save you headaches later. Although, using reserved or special characters is not a good practice, but that's just me.

Comment: I would say ask a new question, this way you will get better opinions other than just mine about it.

Comment: quick question about the script: will it be better if I create a proc? or php script is fine?

Comment: php script is fine, easy to maintain in cronjobs and to debug

Answer (score 0):

use this syntax:

```
drop table \`xd_2012_02 ua\`;
```

this should work with the space